# How do I remove the artist photo from the background of a fullscreen visualization in XBMC/Kodi?

Tags: kodi

When listening to music on XBMC/Kodi, if you click Fullscreen there's a picture in the background of the visualization. How do I remove that album art or whatever it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a feature of the Skin I was using on XBMC. To disable the picture, I went to

```
System -> Settings -> Appearance -> Skin -> Settings -> Background Options
```

and then enabled `Hide Fanart in full screen visualisation`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where Kodi is installed.  Then click on "addons", then "skin.estuary" then "xml".

In that folder are the xml files for the skin "estuary" which is the default.

Then open the xml file "musicvisualization.xml"

Now find the text

```
<control type="image">

<left>0</left>

<top>0</top>

<width>100%</width>

<height>100%</height>

<aspectratio>scale</aspectratio>

<fadetime>400</fadetime>

<animation time="400" end="100" start="0" effect="fade">WindowOpen</animation>

<animation time="300" end="0" start="100" effect="fade">WindowClose</animation>

<texture colordiffuse="88FFFFFF" background="true">$INFO[Player.Art(fanart)]</texture>

</control>
```

It should be near the top of the xml file

Now DELETE THAT TEXT!!!

XD XD XD Now the stupid pictures on the background are gone!

Comment: Please edit your answer by putting code blocks around the contents of the XML file, this will fix the formatting so the tags show up inside the actual answer. Also, I'm not sure you want to get rid of `<control type="image">` without deleting the matching ending tag `</control>`